# I cannot spot my logic error

Tags: java, arrays, methods

when the game executes, the player can enter a move, but then it gets stuck in a loop, and the logic error is in the isWinner method but I can't figure out how to do that without using a bunch of long if statements? help please

```
public class TicTacToe {

    public static char board[] = new char[10];

    public static void resetgame(){
        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) 
            board[x] = '-';    // resets board to all -
    }

    public static void displayBoard(){
        for (int x = 1; x < board.length; x++){
            if (board[x] == '-')
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            else
                System.out.print(board[x] + " ");
            if (x % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isSpotEmpty(int m){
        return (board[m] == '-');           
    }

    public static void getPlayerMove(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your move (1-9): ");
        int move = input.nextInt();
        while (move < 1 || move > 9 || !isSpotEmpty(move)){  //validate move
            System.out.print("Move is not valid. Reenter move (1-9): ");
            move = input.nextInt();
        }
        board[move] = 'X';
    }

    public static void computerMove(){
        int move = ((int)(Math.random() * 9)+1);               
        while (isSpotEmpty(move)==false)
            move = ((int)(Math.random() * 9)+1);
        board[move] = 'O';        
    }

    public static boolean isWinner(char ch){

        for(int x = 1; x < 4; x++){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for(int x = 4; x < 7; x++){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 7; x < board.length; x++){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 1; x < 8; x += 3){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 2; x < 9; x += 3){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 3; x < board.length; x += 3){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 1; x < board.length; x += 4){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        for (int x = 3; x < 8; x += 2){
            while (board[x] != ch)
                return false;}
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isFull(){
        boolean draw = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++){
            while (board[x] != '-')
                draw = true;
        }
        return draw;
    }

    public static boolean isGameDone(){
        if (isWinner('X')){
            System.out.println("Player wins!"); 
            return true;
        }
        if (isWinner('O')){ 
            System.out.println("You suck! Computer wins!"); 
            return true;
        }
        if (isFull()){ 
            System.out.println("Draw!"); 
            return true;
        }
        return false;        
    }

    public static void tictactoe(){
        resetgame();
        displayBoard();
        while (true){ 
            getPlayerMove();           
            displayBoard();
            if (isGameDone()==true) return;           
            System.out.println("Computer's move!");                       
            computerMove();                       
            displayBoard();
            if (isGameDone()==true) return;
            System.out.println("Your move!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        tictactoe();       
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `switch` statement.

Comment: Replace all `while`s with `if` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: tried that...no dice

Comment: Did you try tracing with a debugger? You can easily spot infinite loop situations using one.

Comment: i know where the infinite loop is, because if i comment the isWinner method out of the program it runs just fine, just with no way of determining a winner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor both `isWinner()` and `isFull()` methods. You are stuck in an infinite loop because you are returning immediately after you check for the 1st horizontal row. If that happens to be false, none of the other loops ever gets to execute.

I haven't done a full code review, but the above mentioned bug can be fixed by the below code.

```
boolean finishedFlag = true;
for(int x = 1; x < 4; x++){
    if (board[x] != ch){
        finishedFlag = false;
        break;
    }   
}
if(finishedFlag) return finishedFlag;

/*

...
Check similarly for all horizontal,vertical and diagonal
...

*/

return finishedFlag;
```

The idea is to return once in the function after assessing all possibilities instead of in each loop. 
The below condition facilitates immediate return in case of any successful result:

```
if(finishedFlag) return finishedFlag;
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. thank you for explaining it so well. I refactored it the way you explained and now the program runs fine, it just doesn't determine a winner or if the board is full, it just lets me play until the board is full and gets stuck, even if there is a winner

Comment: @Luke Good to know that it worked. Please do not stop at my suggestion and try to refactor further so that you can make it more readable and concise. I spotted this error and gave a quick workaround and this code can be significantly improved if you gave more thought.

Comment: so I need the condition if(finishedFlag) return finishedFlag; after each for loop?

Comment: @Luke yes, you will be needing it after each for loop. After the loop, you have two options: 1) Game is done(Win/Lose/Draw) 2)Further possibilities to check. The return is for [1].

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code :**
Below code is tested and working.

`isWinner` method

```
public static boolean isWinner(char ch){
    boolean finishFlag = true;
    for(int x = 1; x < 4; x++){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for(int x = 4; x < 7; x++){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 7; x < board.length; x++){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 1; x < 8; x += 3){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 2; x < 9; x += 3){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 3; x < board.length; x += 3){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 1; x < board.length; x += 4){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finishFlag)
        return finishFlag;
    finishFlag = true;
    for (int x = 3; x < 8; x += 2){
        if (board[x] != ch) {
            finishFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return finishFlag;
}
```

`isFull` method

```
public static boolean isFull(){
    boolean draw = false;
    for (int x = 1; x < board.length; x++){
        if (board[x] == '-') {
            draw = false;
            break;
        } else {
            draw = true;
        }
    }
    return draw;
}
```

Edit: initialize x to 1 instead of 0 in isFull()

Comment: result is the same, infinite loop. I was going for a for loop to check each row and column and diagonal on the board for a combo of 3 X's or O's...it didn't like the way i did it

Comment: Luke, you need to refactor isWinner(), that function is taking the long way around.

Comment: How should I refactor it?

Comment: You have only 1 condition `board[x] != ch` to check. Why have you written so many for loops?

Comment: I figured that each loop would check for each individual row and column and the 2 diagonals for 3 sequential like characters

Comment: apparently i have less understanding of for loops than i thought

Comment: no, i tried your solution and the result is the same

Comment: Would -1 if I could. He's writing a program to play Tic-Tac-Toe. The for loops are checking for the winning conditions, namely: a row, a column or a diagonal of the same characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be a little obtuse here. Your problem is due to misuse of the `while` operator. Let's take a look at one of the problems:

```
while (board[x] != '-')
    draw = true;
```

When we look at loops, we want to ask:

1. Is my condition true at the start of the loop?
2. What changes during the loop?
3. Is my condition true at the end of the loop?

The condition is `board[x] != '-'`. At the start of the loop, `board[x]` must necessarily be not equal to `'-'`.

At the end of the `while` loop, `'-'` certainly will not have changed because it is a constant string.

Will `board[x]` have changed? Let's look at the body of the `while` loop. The only thing being done is assigning `true` to `draw`. `x` does not change and neither does `board[x]`.

So, how long will this `while` loop loop? Take a look at the rest of your code where you use `while` and go over how they'll run.

Comment: thank you that was helpful. i changed them all to if's instead. i will try to remember those 3 questions for the future though